# Problems using DLP in Cloud Data Fusion

Tags: google-cloud-data-fusion, google-cloud-dlp

I have been trying to use DLP PII filter in my pipelines. I have given DLP Admin role to my service account, Dataproc cluster account and Default engine account even then the DLP will not work as it will return the following:

```
2022-08-24 10:49:11,140 - ERROR [Executor task launch worker for task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0):o.a.s.u.Utils@94] - Aborting task
com.google.api.gax.rpc.PermissionDeniedException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: PERMISSION_DENIED: Not allowed, access denied for permission serviceusage.services.use.
    at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ApiExceptionFactory.createException(ApiExceptionFactory.java:55) ~[na:na]
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcApiExceptionFactory.create(GrpcApiExceptionFactory.java:72) ~[na:na]
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcApiExceptionFactory.create(GrpcApiExceptionFactory.java:60) ~[na:na]
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcExceptionCallable$ExceptionTransformingFuture.onFailure(GrpcExceptionCallable.java:97) ~[na:na]
    at com.google.api.core.ApiFutures$1.onFailure(ApiFutures.java:68) ~[na:na]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$CallbackListener.run(Futures.java:1056) ~[na:na]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.DirectExecutor.execute(DirectExecutor.java:30) ~[na:na]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.executeListener(AbstractFuture.java:1138) ~[guava-13.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.complete(AbstractFuture.java:958) ~[guava-13.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.setException(AbstractFuture.java:748) ~[guava-13.0.1.jar:na]
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$GrpcFuture.setException(ClientCalls.java:515) ~[na:na]
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$UnaryStreamToFuture.onClose(ClientCalls.java:490) ~[na:na]
    at io.grpc.PartialForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(PartialForwardingClientCallListener.java:39) ~[na:na]
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:23) ~[na:na]
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener$SimpleForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:40) ~[na:na]
    at io.grpc.internal.CensusStatsModule$StatsClientInterceptor$1$1.onClose(CensusStatsModule.java:700) ~[na:na]
    at io.grpc.PartialForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(PartialForwardingClientCallListener.java:39) ~[na:na]
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:23) ~[na:na]
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener$SimpleForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:40) ~[na:na]
    at io.grpc.internal.CensusTracingModule$TracingClientInterceptor$1$1.onClose(CensusTracingModule.java:399) ~[na:na]
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.closeObserver(ClientCallImpl.java:510) ~[na:na]
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.access$300(ClientCallImpl.java:66) ~[na:na]
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.close(ClientCallImpl.java:630) ~[na:na]
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.access$700(ClientCallImpl.java:518) ~[na:na]
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInternal(ClientCallImpl.java:692) ~[na:na]
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:681) ~[na:na]
    at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37) ~[na:na]
    at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:123) ~[na:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[na:1.8.0_322]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_322]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) ~[na:1.8.0_322]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) ~[na:1.8.0_322]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[na:1.8.0_322]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[na:1.8.0_322]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750) ~[na:1.8.0_322]
Caused by: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: PERMISSION_DENIED: Not allowed, access denied for permission serviceusage.services.use.
    at io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:533) ~[na:na]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
```

Is there any way to solve this error?

Comment: Just for clarification, did you do this https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/how-to/using-dlp#grant_permissions

Comment: Is this happening when you are running pipeline preview, or when you are running a deployed pipeline on dataproc? Preview and dataproc will be using different service accounts.

If you are seeing this when running on Dataproc, is it on an ephemeral cluster created by DataFusion or is it a static cluster that was created elsewhere? If it is a static cluster, you will need to make sure to check the "Allow API access to all Google Cloud services in the same project." box under the 'Manage Security' section.